# Do you know where I can find health data sets?

Tags: data-request, medical

I am new to the world of data science. I was wondering if anyone knew where I can find health datasets? Specifically heart disease data on minorities in the US.

Any suggestions or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ctrl+F` the word `health` on http://asdfree.com/

Comment: If you have more details about your goal that would help.  The centers for disease control and prevention (CDC) has some tools; the centers for medicare and medicaid services (CMS) has more data about payments/quality indicators for these conditions; the US department of health and human services (HHS) is probably a good place to look; data.gov may or may not have some of this.  Searches using google for "heart disease mashup <your goal>" may be useful.  The NY Times has a good health reporting team.  The captions/data attribution on their graphics may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend taking a look at the Medicare Expenditure Panel Survey ([MEPS](http://meps.ahrq.gov/mepsweb/)), a nationally representative survey on the health status of individuals that includes patient discharge information. You could also try looking at the National Hospital Discharge Survey ([NHDS](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nhds.htm)), which is a selection of patient discharge data from randomly sampled hospitals.

As a health researcher, you'll definitely want to become acquainted with the ICD 9 diagnosis and procedure codes available by fiscal year [here](http://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes.html). For example, ischemic heart disease is "410**" or "411**". Since you're new to the field, I suggest you seek some in person advice about how to use these two completely different data setups. And it would be worthwhile to become familiar with ICD codes.

Answer (score 2):

The CDC's heart disease maps and data might help you if you want a higher level view:

http://www.cdc.gov/heartdisease/maps_statistics.htm

The first link says:

> This application allows users to view county-level maps of heart disease and stroke by racial/ethnic group, along with maps of social environmental conditions and health services for the entire United States or for a chosen state or territory.